# How to avoid buffering on stdin and stdout?

Tags: rust

When reading from `std::io::stdin()`, input is buffered until `EOF` is encountered. I'd like to process lines as they arrive, rather than waiting for everything to be buffered.

Given a shell function `bar` that runs `echo bar` every second forever, I'm testing this with `bar | thingy`. It won't print anything until I `^C`.

Here's what I'm currently working with:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::timer;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut reader = io::stdin();
    let interval = Duration::milliseconds(1000);

    loop {
        match reader.read_line() {
            Ok(l) => print!("{}", l),
            Err(_) => timer::sleep(interval),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that the output is buffered until EOF. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When reading from std::io::stdin(), input is buffered until EOF is encountered

Why do you say this? Your code appears to work as you want. If I compile it and run it:

```
$ ./i
hello
hello

goodbye
goodbye

yeah!
yeah!
```

The first of each pair of lines is me typing into the terminal and hitting enter (which is what `read_line` looks for). The second is what your program outputs.

```
Err(_) => timer::sleep(interval)
```

This is a bad idea - when input is closed (such as by using `^D`), your program does not terminate.

**Edit**

I created a script `bar`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

i=0

while true; do
    echo $i
    sleep 1
done
```

And then ran it:

```
./bar | ./i
0

0

0
```

Your program continues to work.

Comment: Given a function `bar` that runs `echo bar` every second forever, I'm testing this with `bar | thingy`. It won't print anything until I `^C`. It should really only terminate on EOF. Can I test specifically for EOF in the match? For everything else, it should just retry.

Comment: This is... interesting. `echo` is a builtin in fish, that seems to behave differently in this regard, causing some sort of buffering issue. I've tested again with bash scripts and functions, which work just fine. Well, TIL. Fish is fancy and special. Thanks, Shepmaster!

Comment: "[fish] seems to behave differently in this regard" - sounds like another question for SO! ^_^

Comment: I still have to post that one about checking specifically for EOF from `read_line()` too. Work to do, work to do!